# How can I override a component function specifically for a type on unit?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, components

I have a Health class which has methods TakeDamage() and Die(). My Enemy class has a Health component, so when my Enemy is taking damage Health.TakeDamage() is being executed. How do i go and override Die() method to work differently on different types on enemies.

Comment: Make the methods abstract or virtual in your base class, and then in derived classes you can override those methods (an abstract method **must** be overridden, a virtual method **can** be overriden). https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/override Do **NOT** use member hiding, i.e., do not use the `new` keyword in an attempt to override a method. Method hiding is quite different from method overriding, so don't confuse the two.

Comment: As a side note with regard how you design the data model and logic for your game, this might be a worthwhile read: https://ericlippert.com/2015/04/27/wizards-and-warriors-part-one/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Crate a base class

```
public abstract class Health : MonoBehaviour
{
    // make a member e.g. protected so it is not public but still accesible by inherited classes 
    protected float health = 100f;

    // Now you either can make the method abstract
    // This means every inheritor later HAS to implement this method
    public abstract void Die();

    // or you can make it virtual
    // This means this class already provides an implementation
    // but an inheritor could 
    //  a) simply use it
    //  b) extend it or 
    //  c) completely overrule it
    public virtual void TakeDamage()
    {
        Debug.Log("Ouch!");
        health -= 1;
    }
}
```

**Note:** If your `Health` class doesn't have any `abstract` method, you might want to remove the `abstract` keyword also from the class definition itself and make it only `public class Health : MonoBehaviour`. However, if you want to strictly prevent that the base `Health` class itself is instantiated at all you might want to keep it to make sure that only components of inhertided types may exist.

---

Now you can create different implementations of `Health` either not altering it at all

```
public class NormalHealth : Health
{
    // since it is abstract we have to implement Die
    public override void Die()
    {
        // whatever happens here
    }

    // But if we want to use the default TakeDamage we just do nothing
}
```

or overwriting the default behaviour

```
public class WeakHealth : Health
{
    // Since it is abstract we have to implement Die
    public override void Die()
    {
        // whatever happens here
    }

    // Now we replace the TakeDamage
    public override void TakeDamage()
    {
        // by not calling base.TakeDamage we don't execute the base implementation at all
        Debug.Log("Huge Ouch!");
        health -= 10;
    }
}
```

or extending it instead of replacing it

```
public class HealthWithSound : Health
{
    public AudioSource someAudioSource;
    public AudioClip someClip;

    // Since it is abstract we have to implement Die
    public override void Die()
    {
        // whatever happens here
    }

    // This time we only extend the base's TakeDamage with e.g. sound
    public override void TakeDamage()
    {
        base.TakeDamage();

        someAudioSource.PlayOneShot(someClip);
    }
}
```

Comment: The point is my class doesn't inherit Health class in any way, it just uses an instance of it.

Comment: This applies the same way to classes that are not of type `MonoBehaviour` simply make different Enemy scripts use different Health implementations...